# what happens when I run char * name1 = new char[ 6 ]; strcpy( name1, "Henry" ); char * name2 = name1; name1[0] = 'D';

Tags: c++, char

I was wondering what the value of name1 and name2 becomes when I run this code :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void main()
{

    char * name1 = new char[ 6 ];
    strcpy( name1, "Henry" );

    char * name2 = name1;

    name1[0] = 'D';
}
```

My program for says there are no problems except a warning that

> 'strcpy': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using
>   strcpy_s instead.

To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS.

Every time I run the program nothing happens, and it just shows me a blank screen that says press any key to continue.

Comment: Were you expecting some sort of output? Nothing in here produces output.

Comment: Why would there be anything showing when you are not printing anything on the screen?

Comment: doesn't the value of name1 and name2 change?

Comment: Why would just changing a value print out anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add at the bottom of your code
`std::cout << name1 << " " <<name2 << std::endl;` and you will see wonders.

don't forget to do `delete[] name1;`

Answer (score 1):

Both name 1 and name 2 are pointers with the same value, pointing to the char array, created on the heap, of length six which has the contents 'D','e','n','r','y','\0'

And you need to print something to screen to see anything happen

```
std::cout << name1 << std::endl;
std::cout << name2 << std::endl;
```

Comment: No need for delete or strcpy, but with undefined behavior: trying to change a string literal.